# Django: check whether an object already exists before adding

Tags: python, django

How do I check whether an object already exists, and only add it if it does *not* already exist?

Here's the code - I don't want to add the follow_role twice in the database if it already exists. How do I check first? Use get() maybe - but then will Django complain if get() doesn't return anything?

```
current_user = request.user
follow_role = UserToUserRole(from_user=current_user, to_user=user, role='follow')
follow_role.save()
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's a helper function for this idiom called 'get_or_create' on your model manager:

```
role, created = UserToUserRole.objects.get_or_create(
    from_user=current_user, to_user=user, role='follow')
```

It returns a tuple of (model, bool) where 'model' is the object you're interested in and 'bool' tells you whether it had to be created or not.

Comment: Brilliant. Solves the problem. Thank you! 

Is there a converse function to check whether an object exists, then DELETE it if so, and do nothing if it doesn't?

Comment: I don't know of a helper function off the top of my head, but I think you can get close by doing UserToUserRole.objects.filter(...).delete(). This wouldn't give you a way to inspect whether the object actually existed, though.  You'd have to check the count() on your query set before the delete. Of course, you could take a peek at the get\_or\_create source and create your own helper function easy enough.

Comment: note: `exists()` is supposed to be a little faster than `count()` :)

Comment: exists() must be fresh off the presses, I was unaware that exists() exists.

Comment: @Joe: technically, ``exists()`` isn't even off the presses now. It was committed a month ago and will be in Django 1.2 (http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/11646)

Comment: exists() is supposed to be *a lot* faster than count(), actually, as it doesn't need to scan the entire table.

Comment: the part "whether it had to be created or not" in @JoeHolloway 's answer is very important. So `created = False` means it did not need to be created since it was created before, therefore you can add new information to it. But `created = True` means now you have a brand new obj. Just do not forget to `obj.save()` after adding more information to the object either time.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a recent version of Django, you can use the [unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) option to the UserToUserRole model, and then use the get_or_create() method Joe Holloway showed. This will guarantee that you can't get a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a bool value

```
UserToUserRole.objects.filter(
    from_user=current_user, to_user=user, role='follow'
).exists()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use get(), but you'll have to wrap it with try-except like this:

```
try:
    obj = UserToUserRole.objects.get(from_user=current_user, to_user=user, role='follow')
except UserToUserRole.DoesNotExist:
    # here write a code to create a new object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the check done every time before save you could use the pre save signal to check, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save

Alternatively in the model you could specify unique=True for the property that determines whether an item is the same item, this will cause an Exception (django.db.IntegrityError) to be thrown if you try to save the same thing again.

If you have more than one field together that makes something unique you'll need to use unique_together in the Meta inner class http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together