# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'object'

Tags: django, django-views

after I save the data, i just want to select V_insert_data  and get its id.

How do i solve this problem? any ideas?

```
 V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
    .....
        )
    V_insert_data.save()

 enrollment = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(id = V_insert_data)

 return render("",{"enrollment":enrollment})
```

and i get this error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fetch the object a second time. The `V_insert_dat` *is* the `StudentEnrollmentRecord`, you thus can implement this as:

```
V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.create(
    # …
)
return render(request, '', {'enrollment': V_insert_data})
```

Here `enrollment` is a single `StudentsEnrollmentRecord` object, so you should not iterate over it.

In case `id` is not a primary key (which is probably not advisable), you can fetch the `.id` of the object, and indeed pass that in a `.filter(…)` query:

```
V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.create(
    # …
)
enrollment = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(id=V_insert_data.id)
return render(request, '', {'enrollment': enrollment})
```

Comment: not quite the same. It is possible that the id attribute is not unique and once ```V_insert_data``` is created with an id (say=1), @justin is trying to get the list of all objects with this **id**.

Comment: @MuhammadHashirHassan: if the `id` is not the primary key, then indeed this is different, but unless specified, it is normally something that is assumed. Especially since a lot of Django tooling (unfortunately) makes use of `.id` as primary key, instead of using a more safe `.pk` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
enrollment = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(id = V_insert_dat.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that in the arguments of filter query, instead of an `id` you're passing `V_insert_data` which is actually a `StudentsEnrollmentRecord` model object as you have defined here

```
V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
   .....
       )
```

Instead of giving whole object, give one attribute like id = V_insert_data.id.

```
enrollment = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(id = V_insert_data
.id)
```

This filters works same as where/limit in **select** clause of SQL statement.

UPDATE:

Instead of of filter query after creation, you can also use the combination of create & get like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1821247/11979793